# Returning temporary, why not a rvalue reference?

Tags: c++

A rvalue reference is a temporary object right? Why isn't the following compiling? I thought this function returned a rvalue reference

```
main.cpp:40:12: error: no viable conversion from 'hello3 ()' to 'hello4'
    hello4 lol = returning;
```

in code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class hello {
  public:  
};


class hello2 {
  public:  
};

class hello3 {
  public:  
  hello obj1;
  hello2 obj2;

};


class hello4 {
 public:

 hello4(hello3&&) {
  std::cout << "he";   
 }

};

hello3 returning() {
    hello a;
    hello2 b;
    return {a,b};

}

int main()
{
    hello4 lol = returning;
}
```

I read the move semantics documents but I still don't understand why the above doesn't bind to a rvalue reference

Comment: A reference is never an object. A reference is a kind of *type*. It is also never the type of any object or value.

Comment: That is a good answer, but what kind of object am I returning in the code above? I mean: is it an rvalue?

Comment: `returning` is the name of a function, and thus an lvalue. Lvalues of function type immediately decay to a pointer to the function; the decayed value is a prvalue. (It is also not compatible with the type of `lol`.)

Comment: And finally, functions never "return a reference". The value of a function call expression (unless it is void) is always a value, and thus has object type. The only question is whether it is an lvalue, xvalue or prvalue, which depends on the return *type* of the function. It's much better to say "my function returns an lvalue of type `Foo`", or "returns a `Foo` lvalue".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A rvalue reference is a temporary object right?

No, it's a reference to an object which might or might not be a temporary.

> Why isn't the following compiling?

Because you left the (empty) argument list off the function call:

```
hello4 lol = returning();
                      ^^
```

The error message indicates that your code tries to assign a function, not the result of calling a function, to a variable.

> I thought this function returned a rvalue reference

No, it returns an object, which is just as well since there's nothing for a reference to refer to. But that temporary object can bind to a *rvalue* reference, so it can be used to construct the `hello4`.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler error above is unrelated to what kind of value the object is:

```
hello4 lol = returning;
```

should be

```
hello4 lol = returning();
```

Without the brackets, the compiler thinks you are trying to assign a function to a `hello4` value.  You can see this here:

```
int main()
{
    auto lol = returning;
    hello4 foo = lol();

    return 0;
}
```